# Why does this inheritance fail (method of super class is used) C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have the following classes

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int get_number() {return 1;}
    void tell_me_the_number() {
        cout << "the number is " << get_number() <<"\n";
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    int get_number() {return 2;}
};


int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.tell_me_the_number();
    b.tell_me_the_number();
}
```

I would expect this to output to me:

```
the number is 1
the number is 2
```

But in reality I get twice the number 1 line.

Should not the get_number() method of class B be called when it is a class B? If this is as it should be, how can I obtain the behavior I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mark `get_number` as `virtual` for this to work.

In C++, you get what you pay for. Since polymorphism adds overhead (memory and runtime - pointer to virtual method table & dynamic dispatch), you have to be explicit about which function calls you want resolved at runtime. Since `get_number` isn't `virtual`, the call from  `tell_me_the_number` will be resolved at compile-time and the base class version will be called.